# Не устанавливается dhcp3-server

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, dhcp

```
$ sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Пакет dhcp3-server недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого пакета.
Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел, или доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета «dhcp3-server» не найден кандидат на установку
```

Answer (score 1):

Ты читаешь какой-то старый мануал. На самом деле тебе нужен пакет `isc-dhcp-server`.